# Vertical alignment of a table row with a multiline equation in one cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a 3-by-2 table and in the 3-2 position there should be a 3-line equation.  To align the equation I have used tabular, so I have a table within a table.  But the 3-line equation is centered where it should be vertically aligned with the cell contents of the first column.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{4.25cm}l}
 cell1 & cell2 \\
 cell3 & cell4 \\
 cell5 & \begin{tabular}{ll} $x^2 + 5x$ & $= x^7 + 6x^4 + 1200$\\
                                        & $= x^7 + 2x^4 + 4x^4 + 1200$ \\
                                        & $=x^7 + 2x^4 + 4x^4 + 600 + 600$\end{tabular}
         \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

So "cell5" should be aligned with the first equation.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two straightforward solutions:

- Change `\begin{tabular}{ll}` to `\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}` to inform LaTeX that entries in this row should be top- rather than center-aligned.
- For better-looking mathematics, switch to an `aligned[t]` environment.

The following screenshot shows the effects that `aligned[t]`, `aligned[c]`, and `aligned[b]` have on the placement of the contents of the first column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array,amsmath,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
 cell1 & cell2 \\
 cell3 & cell4 \\
 \midrule
 cell5 & $\begin{aligned}[t] % top alignment
         x^2 + 5x &= x^7 + 6x^4 + 1200\\
                  &= x^7 + 2x^4 + 4x^4 + 1200 \\
                  &= x^7 + 2x^4 + 4x^4 + 600 + 600
         \end{aligned}$  \\
 \midrule
 cell7 & $\begin{aligned} % "[c]" is the default
         x^2 + 5x &= x^7 + 6x^4 + 1200\\
                  &= x^7 + 2x^4 + 4x^4 + 1200 \\
                  &= x^7 + 2x^4 + 4x^4 + 600 + 600
         \end{aligned}$ \\
 \midrule
 cell9 & $\begin{aligned}[b] % bottom alignment
         x^2 + 5x &= x^7 + 6x^4 + 1200\\
                  &= x^7 + 2x^4 + 4x^4 + 1200 \\
                  &= x^7 + 2x^4 + 4x^4 + 600 + 600
         \end{aligned}$ \\
 \midrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using aligned and [t] worked perfectly.  I did not add the booktabs package though.  What was booktabs for?

Comment: @E2R0NS - The `booktabs` package provides various macros for well-spaced horizontal lines, including `\midrule`.